# What does the yellow squiggly underline mean in the eclpise?

Tags: android, eclipse

In my app I saw some words with yellow squiggly underline. What they are  mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are warnings from spell checker.

I could disable it from `Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling.`

Also if the word is within a string then it a spelling error if the yellow line is on a variable or function then it could be a number of things such as the variable or method is not used, or the variable is not initialised, or if on a function call then it could be that the function has been deprecated.as sad @Boardy , thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context. If the word is within a string then it a spelling error if the yellow line is on a variable or function then it could be a number of things such as the variable or method is not used, or the variable is not initialised, or if on a function call then it could be that the function has been deprecated.

Also, if you hover your mouse over the yellow squiggly line it will usually tell you what its warning you about.